# How would I store/construct complete queries, as we do using simple SQL and variables and "+"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, linq

I am not aware of the correct term used for the following procedure in LINQ but i hope there is a way.

### SIMPLE SQL QUERY

Select this from table where alpha would be this and that.

To construct this sort of thing, I would (IS A REQUIREMENT) normally use variables like this:

```
    public return_type select_any(string table_name, string column_name, string where_clause)
    {
        string command_text= "select "+column_name+ " from+" "+table_name+" where "+" "+where_clause;
        // and then whatever the syntax to populated the dataset etc...
    }
```

### now query type of LINQ is like

```
var customerQuery2 = 
    from cust in customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

foreach(var customer in customerQuery2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer.LastName + ", " + customer.FirstName);
}
```

### problem

a thousand tables, I would have to write queries from all tables using there instance, to perform the exactly SAME TYPE select function!

What is the way around this?

Comment: Not an answer, but assembling ad-hoc SQL strings like you do raises serious security and maintainability concerns. But don't you have to call your select_any() for each entity needed anyway? How is this intrinsically "less work" than just using appropriate LINQ queries where needed? And have you considered using a modern ORM if you don't have a DAL readily avl.?

Comment: i know that, no i dont have call for each entity needed. i am aware of the risk, but whats the solution i am asking for, and what are the alternatives, plz provide as answer

Comment: It sounds like you want a Dynamic LINQ solution: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have the `where_clause` as a string, you may as well just use your existing code. Problems:

- you could pass your existing TQL code to `ExecuteQuery`, but you'd need to know what type to expect
- to pull it a part and handle *properly* from LINQ you would have to parse the `where_clause`, which is not a trivial exercise.

However, in LINQ terms what you describe is essentially the same as:

```
public TValue GetSomeValue<TSource, TValue>(
      IQueryable<TSource> source,
      Expression<Func<TSource,TValue>> selector,
      Expression<Func<TSource,bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.Where(predicate).Select(selector).First();
}
```

with usage for example:

```
int id = ...
string name = GetSomeValue(ctx.Customer, cust => cust.Name, cust.Id = id);
```

If you want to work from strings, it is also possible to build expression trees at runtime based on property names / values. Not sure if that is what you want though.

Comment: ur solution is helpful, thanku ,what i want i think cn be described as, "how can i use normal sql statement in work with data using linq, silverlight, ado.net frameowrk i guess...

Comment: @user287745 without writing a TSQL parser, hard. However if your "where" are simple it should be OK

Comment: the solution u provided is called dynamic linq, and if not what is it called, from where can i learn..., asking as i cannot seem to find a link to system.linq.dynamic on msdn!

Comment: and also please provide the namespace for expression, error says "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Expression' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly" thanku

Comment: @user287745 the above is regular LINQ, not dynamic LINQ. Expression is in System.Linq.Expressions.